# How to create RPM for generic Perl module

Tags: perl, rpm, packaging, rpm-spec

I have a generic Perl module that will run on any release of Perl 5. I need to create an RPM for it that will install it into the vendor_perl subdirectory.

I don't want to create different RPMs for SUSE and Red Hat distros, their clones, and their different versions. I have successfully created similar, generic RPMs for non-Perl packages.

I can use %{perl_vendorlib} to map the correct directory, but only for the system where the RPM is created.

What is required in the RPM .spec so that the Perl module file is installed into %{perl_vendorlib} of the target system? Assume the target system could be CentOS 7, RHEL 8, SLES 12, or SLES 15.

Comment: [cpan2rpm](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ECALDER/cpan2rpm-2.028/cpan2rpm)?

Comment: Or cpantorpm, or Lchown. These are all useful for creating a SRPM, but their generated RPMs are OS/ver-specific.